# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var rotate = function(matrix) {
    let rotatedArr = [];
    for(let i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
        for(let k=0; k<matrix.length; k++){
             rotatedArr[i][k] = matrix[matrix.length-1-k][i]
        }
    }
};
```

why this not able to set number to rotatedArr

Comment: Because `rotatedArr[i]` is `undefined`. You have to initialize it `rotatedArr[i] = []`

Comment: Do not use `var`. It is bad and outdated. Use `const` or `let`. And you don't need any of them for functions. Just declare a named function, like this:`function rotate(matrix) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet, `rotatedArr[i]` is `undefined`, so we have to initialize it. We can use the [`||=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment) for this.

```js
var rotate = function(matrix) {
    let rotatedArr = [];
    for(let i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
        for(let k=0; k<matrix.length; k++){
             (rotatedArr[i] ||= [])[k] = matrix[matrix.length-1-k][i]
        }
    }
};
```